# Corona Storyboard doesn't remove element from previous scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

I have a scene in Corona SDK storyboard, a text.
I want it that when it enters the scene, the text becomes "1" and it appears, when it exists the scene i want it disappeared so I set it to "". (an empty string)
But when I get back to the scene, it remains "" and doesnt sit it to 1 again.

```
function scene:enterScene( event )
    local screenGroup = self.view
    storyboard.purgeScene("mainmenuscene")
    backbtn:addEventListener("touch",backbtn)
    leveltext = display.newText("1", 75, 1.7, native.systemFontBold, 20)
    leveltext:setTextColor(255,255,255)
```

end

and here is the exit scene function

function scene:exitScene( event )

`local screenGroup = self.view

-- remove touch listener for image
backbtn:removeEventListener( "touch", backbtn )
leveltext = display.newText("", 75, 1.7, native.systemFontBold, 20)
leveltext:setTextColor(255,255,255)`

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I fixed it.
Apparently in the exit scene function I should've done leveltext:removeSelf() instead of moving it to ""

Comment: Why you do not use `screenGroup:insert( leveltext )` in the enterScene listener? If you do that, then storyboard will delete it with scene when user will leave scene.

Comment: I am very new to Lua and Corona, this is actually my first app.
Thanks for the advice!